# Restricting Bash Filename Expansion

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

In order to write files to a USB volume I want to rename filenames containing '?', '"', '*' or ':' to replace any of these characters with a space. But I'm having trouble with the '*'. My bash script is

```
for file in * 
do 
    mv -v "'"$file"'" "'"$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\(.*\)[?"*:]\(.*\)/\1 \2/')"'" 
done
```

The '*' keeps getting expanded into the filenames in the current directory. I've tried using

```
set -f
```

but then the initial 'in *' doesn't work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash

Comment: @Panki Thanks, but I thought I'd done that. Exactly how should it be written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure that you quote you filenames properly and there will be no issues.

```
for name in ./*; do
    newname=${name//[?\"*:]/ }
    if [ "$newname" != "$name" ]; then
        mv -iv "$name" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

Your `"'"$file"'"` actually leaves `$file` completely unquoted (surrounded by single quotes, but these do not quote the variable or its value since they are themselves quoted).

See also:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

---

Regarding your `sed` bit.

`sed` has a neat little command that many seem to overlook called `y`:

```
sed 'y/?"*:/    /'
```

This would change all characters in the first part of the expression to the corresponding character in the second part (here all spaces).

`tr` works too:

```
tr '?"*:' '    '
```

But in this case, it would be more convenient to use the built in parameter substitution facility of `bash` to make the changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have some strange stuff happening with you quotes.

Start by changing the `"'"` to `"`